# How can I keep comments when minifying my React code?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have the following JSX in a React app:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* A JSX comment */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am using webpack to compile and minify the code.

In my webpack plugins I am using UglifyJsPlugin to try and keep the comments:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin( {
    compress: {
        warnings: false,
        // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
        // Pending further investigation:
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
        comparisons: false,
    },
    mangle: {
        safari10: true,
        except: ['__', '_n', '_x', '_nx' ],
    },
    output: {
        comments: true,
        // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
        ascii_only: true,
    },
    extractComments: false,
    sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
} ),
```

`comments:true` is preserving some comments from React but my comment from JSX `/* A JSX comment */`, is being stripped from the minified code. How can I prevent that comment from being stripped out of the minified/production code?

Also my Babel module rule with comments turned on:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            // @remove-on-eject-begin
            babelrc: false,
            presets: [ require.resolve( 'babel-preset-cgb' ) ],
            // @remove-on-eject-end
            // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
            // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
            // directory for faster rebuilds.
            cacheDirectory: false,
            comments: true,
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: do comments stays if you don't use uglifyJs?

Comment: no they do not stay

Comment: so it's not about UglifyJs, it's about `babel`or maybe jsx transform plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dived into Babel's repo and find a bug reported

How to preserve jsx comment after babel transform [#7153](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7153)

it has been fixed last year and fix came into [7.0.0-beta.37](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.37). so if that feature is really important to you you have to bump Babel's version.

[UPD] I believe it's just a edge case for bug mentioned above.

As we can see at [online sandbox](https://babeljs.io/repl) your code is transpiled into

```
render() {
  return React.createElement("div", null);
}
```

but once I put at least explicit `null`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {null/* A JSX comment */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

it will not strip comments:

```
render() {
  return React.createElement("div", null, null
  /* A JSX comment */
  );
}
```

So comments are stripped only if there are no other tokens in the same block.

since older bug has been closed forever I've put new one #10118 so whoever found this topic looking for a solution better check this ticket for updates

Comment: Thanks for the answer @skyboyer! I am using Babel 7 but the comments are still stripped. I also added my Babel webpack config to my question and have comments set to true there too.

Comment: I've filed a new issue into their github: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10118 could you please comment there why is it needed at all so they may take into account while triaging

Comment: Thank you for providing so much awesome help! Adding `null` before the comments is great!