# How to create a non-empty comment node using JSX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, vuejs3

I've tried the following with no luck, wanted to produce a `<!-- Baz -->` *comment node*:

```
export default {
  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        Foo
        {/* Baz */}
      </strong>
    )
  },
}
```

Comment: What happens as a result? And why is there a comma?

Comment: @3r1c Produce a `<!-- Baz -->` comment node in the DOM tree, trailing comma is a preference thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not strictly JSX, I haven't better way to achieve this:

```
import { Comment, h } from 'vue'

export default {
  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        Foo
        {h(Comment, 'Baz')}
      </strong>
    )
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works `&lt;-- Baz --&gt;`

answer 2:

Babel transform will remove jsx comments,you can update your babel version, view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666638/how-can-i-keep-comments-when-minifying-my-react-code) or you can use some [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015336/how-to-render-a-html-comment-in-react)

Comment: That's not a comment node tho.

Comment: Babel transform will remove jsx comments,you can update your babel version, view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666638/how-can-i-keep-comments-when-minifying-my-react-code) or you can use some [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015336/how-to-render-a-html-comment-in-react)